# Adobe Illustrator CS5 64 bit on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Trying to find out if there is a seperate or included **64-bit** version of **Adobe Illustrator for Windows** like Photoshop has.

Comment: I think you've misread 'AI CS5' (Adobe Illustrator) as 'All CS5 [applications]' in the Adobe thread.

Comment: Oops! I think you're right! So how could I manage to read it that way? Wow... This question will self-destruct in a day... +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe Illustrator does not have a 64-bit version. Only Photoshop, Premiere, Media Encoder, and After Effects have 64-bit versions. Illustrator is 32-bit only.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2785410#2785410), some software like Photoshop includes 64-bit versions, but Illustrator does not. This may be it, though it's mostly about Mac and I have no findings for an official word about it.